# Question on the deduction of the integral form of remainder of Taylor series

Tags: calculus, integration, taylor-expansion

**[Theorem deduction]** First we have a generalized form of integration by parts
$$
\begin{align}
\int u(x)v^{(n+1)}(x)dx=\sum_{i=0}^n(-1)^iu^{(i)}v^{(n-i)}+(-1)^{n+1}\int u^{(n+1)}(x)v(x)dx &&(G)
\end{align}
$$
From this equation we have
$$
\begin{align}
&\int_{x_0}^{x}(x-t)^nf^{(n+1)}(t)dt\\
&=\left[(x-t)^nf^{(n)}(t)+n(x-t)^{n-1}f{(n-1)}(t)+...+n!f(t)\right]_{x_0}^{x}+\int_{x_0}^x0 \cdot f(t)dt &&(G')\\
&=n!f(x)-n!\left[f(x_0)+f'(x_0)(x-x_0)+...+\frac{f^{(n)}(x_0)}{n!}(x-x_0)^n\right]\\
&=n!R_n(x)
\end{align}
$$
Where $R_n(x)$ is the remainder of Taylor series.

**[Question]** I'm wondering where did $(-1)^i$ go in the step from $(G)$ to $(G')$. Why do all the terms become positive?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: In $(G')$ since you are deriving wrt to t , then the derivative of $ (x-t)^i$ is $-i(x-t)^{i-1}$. So you have $-$ from the intial formula and $ -$ from the integration . In general, for  $ u=(x-t)^n$ we have $u^{(i) } =(-1)^in.(n-1)..(n-i+1)(x-t)^i$

Comment: @Nizar Thank you! Why don't you answer in a post, so I can mark your post as accepted. In addition, I wanna ask one more thing. The term $\int 0\cdot f(t)dt$ should be $(-1)^{n+1}\int 0\cdot f(t)dt$ exactly, is that right?

Comment: maybe power $n+1$ and not $n$.